How can I get my scatter plot to plot row 1 in X axis and rows 2 & 3 in Y axis
Hello when I try to create my chart it plots the time in seconds in the x axis and number of drinks in the y axis. I can't work out how to flip this around.
Essentially I'm trying to compare how the number of drinks affects the times shown between 2 people
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18agHdNQtFlwG2J7IcZoMH-G3nE5EbM7yvl11kbJ4iD8/edit?usp=drivesdk


I got the following chart with both the axis picked up by sheet-default: no. of drinks on X and time on Y. If for some reason its not happening on your end, you may have to manually change the axis-selections


This is exactly what I'm trying to do, under series I am unable to select me or my friend. The only option available to me is number of drinks

Create it in your test sheet & showcase us how you are doing it exactly

I have copied the sheet onto a new tab but can't seem to duplicate the issue on the same sheet any longer.
